# HTML <video> aspect ratio <> iOS <> faceMode: "environment" <> How to get vertical video from back camera?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webrtc, augmented-reality

I am using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` to get a back camera feed.

It's working fine, however, I would like to **receive the video in vertical mode.**

This is my current setting, however, when running on an iOS device, the video is still in horizontal mode, and if I try to save an image, that too gets saved in landscape mode.

It works perfectly fine on desktop, i.e. the video and images I save are all in portrait mode.

Any ideas on what needs to be done?

```
  const constraints = {
    video: {
      facingMode: "environment",
      aspectRatio: 0.463,
      width: {
        ideal: 333.33
      },
      height: {
        ideal: 720
      }
      },
  };
```